# Android TextInput hint text color

Tags: java, android, xml, android-xml

I have this `TextInputLayout` and `EditText` and my text hint is black color and I want to change it.

By the way when the hint is going on top its color is white

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.App.TextInputLayout">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/prompt_password"
                android:imeActionId="@+id/login"
                android:imeActionLabel="@string/action_sign_in_short"
                android:imeOptions="actionUnspecified"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textColorHint="@android:color/white" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Styles

```
<style name="TextAppearance.App.TextInputLayout" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

[image]

Comment: Do you solved it?

Comment: @josedlujan You have to put " android:textColorHint="@color/yourColor" " in the "android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout":

Answer (score 7):

You need to put the `android:textColorHint="@color/yourColor"` in the `TextInputLayout`, just like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.App.TextInputLayout"
    android:textColorHint="@color/yourColor">
```

Or in your application theme:

```xml
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/yourColor</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 4):

1. Use this to change the hint color.

> ```
> editText.setHintTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
> ```

2. Simply add this in your layout for the EditText :

> ```
> android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF"
> ```

3. And if you want like this then you can do,

> ```
> editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
>
>   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,int arg3){
>     //do something
>   }
>
>   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) 
>   {
>     //do something 
>   }
>
>   public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
>     if(arg0.toString().length() <= 0)            
>       tv.setHintTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
>   } 
> });
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You should define more attributes like this:

```
<style name="TextAppearance.App.TextInputLayout" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">
   <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
   <item name="android:textColorHint">@android:color/white</item>
   <item name="colorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
   <item name="colorAccent">@android:color/white</item>

   <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/someColor</item>
   <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/someColor</item>
   <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/someColor</item>

</style>
```

Comment: @KirillZotov did you define these three attributes? `<item name="colorControlNormal">@color/someColor</item>
   <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/someColor</item>
   <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/someColor</item>`

Comment: also make sure that parent of the theme is `TextAppearance.AppCompat`. I have updated my answer. Please check again.

Comment: @KirillZotov check the updated code, I have changed the parent of theme. Now it is `TextAppearance.AppCompat`.

Comment: Yeah, I got even this, thanks. By the way I have this theme  `parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">` at my activity.