# How to apply different colors for hint and error text | material design text field

Tags: android, android-styles, android-textinputlayout

How can I use different colors for hint and error text in error state? I used material components and I can't understand how it can be done.
I expect this result

[image]

But i have
[image]

My styles

```
<style name="StyleTextInput" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox">
    <item name="android:textCursorDrawable">@null</item>
    <item name="boxBackgroundColor">@color/window_background</item>
    <item name="boxBackgroundMode">filled</item>
    <item name="background">@color/window_background</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/window_background</item>
    <item name="hintTextColor">@color/grey_alpha_color_50</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/grey_alpha_color_50</item>
    <item name="hintTextAppearance">@style/Hint.TextAppearance</item>
    <item name="errorIconDrawable">@null</item>
    <item name="boxStrokeErrorColor">@color/red</item>
    <item name="errorTextColor">@color/red</item>
    <item name="errorTextAppearance">@style/Error.TextAppearance</item>

    <item name="materialThemeOverlay">@style/MaterialThemeOverlay</item>
    <item name="boxStrokeColor">@color/stroke_color_selector</item>
    <item name="boxCollapsedPaddingTop">0dp</item>
    <item name="endIconTint">@null</item>
</style>

<style name="MaterialThemeOverlay">
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/white</item>
    <item name="editTextStyle">@style/TextInputEdit</item>
</style>

<style name="TextInputEdit" parent="Base.Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputEditText">
    <item name="background">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:textCursorDrawable">@null</item>
</style>

<style name="Hint.TextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/grey_alpha_color_50</item>
</style>

<style name="Error.TextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/red</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out for hint color [Android TextInput hint text color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36425707/android-textinput-hint-text-color/53832701)

and for the error color, try editing the `app:errorTextColor` of the enclosing `com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout`.

Comment: You can see, I set errorTextColor and hintTextColor in styles. But if i set error(TextInputLayout.setError), hint view use errorColor

Comment: I think that is a state change in the app, you can try to solve that programmatically

Comment: when you are setting the error , try changing the color with setHintTextColor();

Comment: try to call setHintTextColor after setError but still see red hint :(